# Set cookie is have an issue with path in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I tried to set cookie on my Wordpress website.

So i write the following code on `header.php`

```
if($_REQUEST['my-key'] !==""){
        $value=$_REQUEST['my-key'];
        setcookie('new_my_code', $value, time() + (86400));
    }
```

But the problem of this is this cookie is only setting up with the corresponding page , not the entire domain .

For example if someone take **www.mywebsite.com/about/?my-key=123**

then the cookie is set on /about path only . I want to set it on entire pages or entire domain , i tried many things nothing works

```
Try 1) header.php

    if($_REQUEST['my-key'] !==""){
        $value=$_REQUEST['my-key'];
        setcookie('new_my_code', $value, time() + (86400), '/');
    }



Try 2) header.php

    if($_REQUEST['my-key'] !==""){
        $value=$_REQUEST['my-key'];
        setcookie('new_my_code', $value, time() + (86400), '/', '.mywebsite.com');
    }



Try 3) header.php

    if($_REQUEST['my-key'] !==""){
        $value=$_REQUEST['my-key'];
        setcookie('new_my_code', $value, time() + (86400), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }



Try 4) functions.php

    add_action( 'init', 'setting_my_first_cookie' );

    function setting_my_first_cookie() {
     if($_REQUEST['my-key'] !==""){
        $value=$_REQUEST['my-key'];
        setcookie('new_my_code', $value, time() + (86400), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
    }




5)

    $rp_path   = isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ? current( explode( '?', wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) ) : '';
    setcookie('new_my_code', $value, time() + (86400),$rp_path, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true);
```

I tired most things that i found on web to make it work . But whatever i am doing cookie is only setting on the same page . So please help

Is there any solution ? Is there any jQuery Solution ?

Answer (score 0):

JS is good for this

`document.cookie` is all you need but you can wrap it in a function and execute it

```
   function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));//set e
      var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
      document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }
```

example from W3 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

then you have to run the function on an event
// onpageload

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
setCookie("cookieName", "value", 10);
});
```

you can also try dynamically setting the cookie with getting the relative permalink

```
function get_relative_permalink( $url ) {
    $url = get_permalink();
    return str_replace( home_url(), "", $url );
}


   if($_REQUEST['my-key'] !==""){
        $value=$_REQUEST['my-key'];
        $path = get_relative_permalink();
        setcookie('new_my_code', $value, time() + (86400),$path, '.mywebsite.com');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue with WordPress , i guess the reason is because the headers are already sent when your script reaches your set-cookies line !

you can check for that using headers_sent() if it return true so setting cookies will not work .

this line :

```
setcookie('new_my_code', $value, time() + (86400), '/');
```

must set cookies for root website

put it in functions.php like this

```
function setting_my_first_cookie() {
   if($_REQUEST['my-key'] !==""){
      $value=$_REQUEST['my-key'];
      setcookie('new_my_code', $value, time() + (86400), '/');  
   }
}
add_action( 'init', 'setting_my_first_cookie' );
```

Hope this help .